# How can i replace multiple value in specific column with R

Tags: r

i'm try toreplace values (numerical)  in specific column with specific text  related with condition

for example :
if i have this date frame " **test** " contians from only one column

```
  test<-data.frame(x=1:9)


test$x[test$x<4] <- "good"
test$x[test$x>4&test$x<7] <- "very good"
test$x[test$x>7] <- "excellent"

View(test)
```

i need to repalce  with :

the valuses leess than 4 with "good"

and valuses between than 4  and 7 with " very good"

and valuses more than 7   " excellent "

- i try this code in big number but the result isn't what i looking for its show me unstable values
- i supposed i see in this column just text from "  good to excellent" but also shows me a numbers !?

### is there any another code working fine or   i did someting wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

test<-data.frame(x=1:9)

test %>% 
  mutate(x = 
    case_when(
      x < 4 ~ "good",
      x >= 4 & x < 7 ~ "very good",
      x >= 7 ~ "excellent"
    )
  )
#>           x
#> 1      good
#> 2      good
#> 3      good
#> 4 very good
#> 5 very good
#> 6 very good
#> 7 excellent
#> 8 excellent
#> 9 excellent
```